# Laravel 6 - Validation not working at all

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm submitting a form to controller and validating it. I don't know why but if the validation fails, it doesn't throw any error and reload the page. besides that, the bail rule isn't working on first check.

```
<form action="{{ route('backoffice.sgc.registar_minuta') }}" method="POST">
@csrf

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label><b>Designação&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
        <input type="text" name="designation" placeholder="Parcela ou Alveolo ou ..." class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label><b>Abreviação&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">*</span></b></label>
        <input type="text" name="abreviation" placeholder="P ou A ou ..." class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<p></p>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label><b>N.º Máximo de Titulares</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="max_titulares" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo numérico." />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label><b>N.º Máximo de Acompanhantes</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="max_acompanhantes" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo numérico." />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label><b>N.º Máximo de Crianças</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="max_criancas" class="form-control" placeholder="Campo numérico." />
    </div>
</div>

<hr />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registar Minuta</button>&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Limpar Formulário</button>
```

```
/**
 * Display the Backoffice for SGC application
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function sgc()
{
    return view('backoffice.sgc.index', [
        'areas'         =>  DB::connection('db_connection_sgc')->table('tbl_assignable_areas')->select()->get(),
        'equipments'    =>  DB::connection('db_connection_sgc')->table('tbl_assignable_equipments')->select()->get(),
        'deadlines'     =>  DB::connection('db_connection_sgc')->table('tbl_assignable_contract_deadline')->select()->get(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created document in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function sgc_registar_minuta(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());

    // input validation
    $request->validate([
        'designation'       =>  'bail|required',
        'abreviation'       =>  'bail|required',
        'max_titulares'     =>  'bail|required',
        'max_acompanhantes' =>  'bail|required',
        'max_criancas'       =>  'bail|required',
    ]);

    // redirect to tickets.index
    return redirect()
            ->route('backoffice.sgc')
            ->with('success', 'stored!!!');
}
```

On blade template, I work the errors int his way:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <script type="text/javascript">Swal.fire({ type: "error", title: "{{ $error }}", showConfirmButton: true }); </script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I believe it's a really simple thing but I'm not getting it! 
Thanks!!

Comment: If you're going to be looping over the errors, I don't think there's any point to using `bail|required` for each error. Just use `required`, and display the multiple errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but didn't resolved the problem. Regards

Comment: Are you omitting any form fields? You won't get any validation errors if you fill out the form. Aside from that, does `$this->validate()` work instead of `$request->validate()`?

Comment: you should have code for redirect withErrors when validator failes.

Comment: @TimLewis, No, I'm not. I'm validating everything and filling one 1 field. Next field should got error.

Comment: @PrateikDarji, hmm didn't know that. I will research a little about this.

Comment: @PrateikDarji Only if you're using a manual validator... `$this->validate()` or `$request->validate()` should do the redirect automatically.

Comment: Yes, and if you use direct request validator as described in my answer it will automatically redirected with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.

I think I found the problem...

Im using $request->validate([...]); , so this should redirect if an rules catch an error.

I commited my project to a linux server, configured laravel to use memcached on both session and cache driver, guess what... Everything works like a charm!